# Why does ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occur and how to avoid it in Android?

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

Why does `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occur and how to avoid it in Android?

Comment: Well the naive answer is "Because you tried to access an array index that doesn't exist, and is thus outside the bounds of the array", meaning an index that is too large or too small (most probably negative in the latter case). It is, however, essentially impossible to help you with your specific situation without A) Much more description or B) A code sample (preferably B, really).

Comment: even shorter answer: don't access an array outside its declared bounds.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690028/array-index-out-of-bounds or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044578/java-arrayindexoutofbounds-exception

Comment: This is a Java 101 type of question. I'd suggest brushing up on Java first and only afterwards should you tackle Android development.

Comment: Have you considered reading the Java documentation for that exception? Revolutionary idea (of reading the documentation), I know! - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Answer (score 6):

This exception is thrown when you try to access an array item that doesn't exist:

```
String [] myArray = new String[2];

myArray[2] = "something"; // Throws exception
myArray[-1] = "something"; // Throws exception
```

You should check that your index is not negative and not higher than the array length before accessing an array item.

Answer (score 4):

> **Why does ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occur [...]**

Here is a quotation from [the Java Language Specification: 10.4 Array Access](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html):

> *All array accesses are checked at run time; an attempt to use an index that is less than zero or greater than or equal to the length of the array causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to be thrown.*

> **[...] and how to avoid it in Android?**

You make sure you're indices are within the range [0...`yourArray.length`-1].

(Note the -1 above. Arrays are 0-indexed which means that you'll find the first element at index 0, and the last at length-1.)

Comment: +1 For the answer ... but then I can index into an array of length 0 using -1? :p

Comment: Well no, since 0 is not in range [0...-1] (the empty set :)  But sure, all the last elements of the empty array will be found at index -1 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It means, as said, that you access an array-item that does not exist.

Most of the time it is because someone asks for the size of an array (length) and then tries to read the last item as `array[length]`.
But arrays start at **0**, so the last you can read is `array[length-1]`

Sollution is ofcourse *do not access items that do not exist*

Answer (score 0):

This exception has nothing to do with Android because Android Applications uses Java Programming language. Rather you should ask like `how to avoid it in Java?`.

And the bottom line is that you are trying to access the value at the invalid index in your Array.

Read the official documentation here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html