# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException bug in medata extractor lib

Tags: android, image, metadata

I'm using the metada-exttractor in android ver.: 2.7.0.

And this lib sometimes throw this exception:`

```
    STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=256; index=352
at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:299)
at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegSegmentData.getOrCreateSegmentList(Unknown Source)
at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegSegmentData.addSegment(Unknown Source)
at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegSegmentReader.readSegments(Unknown Source)
at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.process(Unknown Source)
at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)
at com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)
at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)
at com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(Unknown Source)
at com.hexar.filebroswer.database.PhotoRecord.getLastModifyDate(PhotoRecord.java:99)
```

This throws only sometimes in same cases, I CANNOT catch or solve this problem because is in the library....

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958235/why-does-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-occur-and-how-to-avoid-it-in-android

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=256; index=352` You are passing an index greater than the length of the array. try checking out the index being passed to the array

Comment: Its third part library in jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a corrupted metadata in your image. Have you tried other images?

This forum [post](http://jalbum.net/forum/thread.jspa?threadID=33541) seems to suggest that was the cause for some other users.

Comment: yes probably there was metada corrupted, but i CAn may add exception in this lib in jar.file?