# How to handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for arraylist

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm a newbie to android. In my application in some cases ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs. But i'm not able to reproduce the same. Can anyone help me to fix this exception
**Logcat**

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 6
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
   at com.beco.ibeco.model.Store.getOpenHoursString(Store.java:209)
   at com.beco.ibeco.app.store.StoreDetailFragment.populateStoreViews(StoreDetailFragment.java:491)
   at com.beco.ibeco.app.store.StoreDetailFragment.access$700(StoreDetailFragment.java:99)
   at com.beco.ibeco.app.store.StoreDetailFragment$3.onLoadFinished(StoreDetailFragment.java:408)
   at com.beco.ibeco.app.store.StoreDetailFragment$3.onLoadFinished(StoreDetailFragment.java:386)
   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:479)
   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:447)
   at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:126)
   at com.beco.ibeco.content.ModelLoader.deliverResult(ModelLoader.java:61)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:249)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:77)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:476)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:493)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

And this is the code

```
    public String getOpenHoursString() {
    MutableDateTime now = MutableDateTime.now();
    int dayIndex = now.getDayOfWeek() - 1;
    if (hours != null) {
        OpeningHour bopHours = hours.get(dayIndex);
        if (bopHours != null && bopHours.openTime != null && bopHours.closeTime != null) {
            DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
            DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm a");
            DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").withZoneUTC();
            DateTime open = DateTime.parse(bopHours.openTime, parseFormat).toDateTime(timeZone);
            DateTime close = DateTime.parse(bopHours.closeTime, parseFormat).toDateTime(timeZone);
            if ((now.getHourOfDay() >= open.getHourOfDay()) && (now.getHourOfDay() < close.getHourOfDay())) {
                return String.format("Open till - %s", format.print(close)).toLowerCase();
            } else {
                return String.format("%s - %s", format.print(open), format.print(close)).toLowerCase();
            }

        }
    }

    return "";
}

public String getOpenCloseString(int type){
    Map<Integer,String> mOpeningHours = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (OpeningHour bopHours : hours) {
        DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm a");
        DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").withZoneUTC();
        DateTime open = DateTime.parse(bopHours.openTime, parseFormat).toDateTime(timeZone);
        DateTime close = DateTime.parse(bopHours.closeTime, parseFormat).toDateTime(timeZone);
        mOpeningHours.put(bopHours.day,String.format("%s - %s", format.print(open), format.print(close)).toUpperCase());
    }
    return mOpeningHours.get(type) == null?"closed":mOpeningHours.get(type);
}
```

**populateStoreViews()**

```
private void populateStoreViews(Store store) {
    if (store == null || mWideImageView == null || mStoreLogo == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (store.isFavourite() && Beco.getApp().currentUser().isSignedIn()) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite));
    } else {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favourite_unselected_15dp));
    }

    setTitle(store.getName());

    ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(store.getImageUri(Store.IMAGE_WIDE, Beco.getApp().getDensity()))
            .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
            .build();
    DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
            .setImageRequest(request)
            .setOldController(mWideImageView.getController())
            .build();
    GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder builder =
            new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(getContext().getResources());
    GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = builder
            .setFadeDuration(200)
            .setPlaceholderImage(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.image_mall_default))
            .build();


    mWideImageView.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
    mWideImageView.setController(controller);

    containerStoreLogo.setCardBackgroundColor(store.getColor());

    ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(store.getImageUri(Store.IMAGE_SQ, Beco.getApp().getDensity()))
            .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
            .build();
    DraweeController draweeController = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
            .setImageRequest(imageRequest)
            .setOldController(mStoreLogo.getController())
            .build();
    GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder genericDraweeHierarchyBuilder =
            new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(getContext().getResources());
    GenericDraweeHierarchy genericDraweeHierarchy = genericDraweeHierarchyBuilder
            .setFadeDuration(200)
            .setPlaceholderImage(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.img_store_loader))
            .build();


    mStoreLogo.setHierarchy(genericDraweeHierarchy);
    mStoreLogo.setController(draweeController);
    mAddressView.setText(store.getName());
    mStatusView.setText(store.getOpenHoursString());/*this line*/
    mDistanceView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.distance_string, store.getDistanceString(Beco.getApp().getLocation())));

}
```

And this is the sample response for the arraylist from the server

```
hours: [
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T16:30:00Z",
day: 1,
open_time: "2017-05-03T06:00:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T16:30:00Z",
day: 2,
open_time: "2017-05-03T06:00:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T16:30:00Z",
day: 3,
open_time: "2017-05-03T06:00:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T16:30:00Z",
day: 4,
open_time: "2017-05-03T06:00:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T16:30:00Z",
day: 5,
open_time: "2017-05-03T06:00:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T16:30:00Z",
day: 6,
open_time: "2017-05-03T06:00:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T16:30:00Z",
day: 7,
open_time: "2017-05-03T06:00:00Z"
}
]
```

**EDIT**

I'm getting these exception on **Sundays**(which will give dayIndex as 7-1=6)

For some stores I'm getting **response** as

```
hours: [
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T15:00:00Z",
day: 2,
open_time: "2017-05-03T04:30:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T15:00:00Z",
day: 3,
open_time: "2017-05-03T04:30:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T15:00:00Z",
day: 4,
open_time: "2017-05-03T04:30:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T15:00:00Z",
day: 5,
open_time: "2017-05-03T04:30:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T15:00:00Z",
day: 6,
open_time: "2017-05-03T04:30:00Z"
},
{
close_time: "2017-05-03T15:00:00Z",
day: 7,
open_time: "2017-05-03T04:30:00Z"
}
]
```

Please any one help me ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occur and how to avoid it in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958235/why-does-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-occur-and-how-to-avoid-it-in-android)

Comment: Array indexes starts with 0. You need to revise your Java concepts before writing so much of code :o

Comment: Basically you expect your List to have at least as much entries as days in the week and this is not the case. You have only 6 entries in your List so when you try to get the last day of the week you're outside the boundaries. So something is wrong in the data you get from the server. Or you don't build your "hours" list correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to check whether size of arrayList `hours` is less than `dayIndex`

```
    public String getOpenHoursString() {
    MutableDateTime now = MutableDateTime.now();
    int dayIndex = now.getDayOfWeek() - 1;
    if (hours != null && hours.length>dayIndex) {
        OpeningHour bopHours = hours.get(dayIndex);
        if (bopHours != null && bopHours.openTime != null && bopHours.closeTime != null) {
            DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
            DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm a");
            DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").withZoneUTC();
            DateTime open = DateTime.parse(bopHours.openTime, parseFormat).toDateTime(timeZone);
            DateTime close = DateTime.parse(bopHours.closeTime, parseFormat).toDateTime(timeZone);
            if ((now.getHourOfDay() >= open.getHourOfDay()) && (now.getHourOfDay() < close.getHourOfDay())) {
                return String.format("Open till - %s", format.print(close)).toLowerCase();
            } else {
                return String.format("%s - %s", format.print(open), format.print(close)).toLowerCase();
            }

        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

now it's ok

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somewhere in your code hours isn`t properly initialized.

**but my money would be on** 
        int dayIndex = now.getDayOfWeek() - 1; 
probably resulting in a negative value and making some caca here
        OpeningHour bopHours = hours.get(dayIndex);

Place some break points, check those values and/or dump then to Log and get back to us ;-)