# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 49, size is 0

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, recyclerview-layout

where I scroll RecyclerView got problem on this code

this one from RecyclerView.Adapter

```
return items.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
```

and this one from activity

```
lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(MyActivity.this, 2);
        rView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
        lLayout.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch(rcAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                    case RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_ITEM:
                        return 1;
                    case RecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_PROG:
                        return 2;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Got Exception :

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 49, size is 0 
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

help me how to fixed this
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occur and how to avoid it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958235/why-does-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-occur-and-how-to-avoid-it-in-android)

Comment: It says there are **no items in your array list and you're trying to access the 49th item**.

Comment: post your adapter class